# Calculating variable using attribute laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a simple code where I output the new age of a person. If a person is aged 17, it should output 18.

But I'm calculating this on blade (which I think is bad). And I'm trying attribute to handle this, but since I'm very new to Laravel, I don't know how to handle it.

Please help me...

**This is how I calculate**
`{{date('Y') - $birth->birth_date->year + 1}}`

It is decreasing the current year from the record and getting the current age, then adding 1.
Is there a more reliable way to do it (like using attribute)?

I've tried adding attribute to my eloquent but I can't find the way

Comment: Why show 18 if the person is 17?

Comment: My project shows birthdays on current day, and it should show the 'new age' of the person.

Comment: Year is not a strong attribute then because date also matters. There is a difference between 17 years running and 17 years completed and 18 running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is best defined as a mutator/accessor on your model:

`User.php` (or whatever `$birth` is)

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

class User extends Model {
  protected $dates = ['birth_date'];

  public function getAgeAttribute() {
    return Carbon::now()->diffInYears($this->birth_date);
  }
  ...
}
```

Then, in your `.blade.php` file:

```
{{ $birth->age }} // 18 (or 17)
```

Comment: Working, you made me understand mutators in just minutes! I've been reading docs and watching tutorials since hours. Waiting 2 minutes to accept the answer, thanks!

Comment: No problem! Happy to help :) Mutators are definitely super helpful in Laravel